# Ignore nested groups in regex lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex, safari, mobile-safari

Take the following:

```
More writing. More writing?    More writing!
```

I'd like to split the string into its sentences each with the whitespace that follows it.

Thus my desired result is:

```
["More writing.", "More writing?    ", "More writing!"]
```

After finding out that Safari has yet to support lookbehind checks for Regex, here is my attempt at a lookahead equivalent.

First, I reverse the string, then split with:

```
/(?=\s+!|\s+\?|\s+(?:\.{3}|\.))/g
```

This works, except it counts the multiple spaces multiple times giving the result:

```
 ["More writing. More writing? ", " ", " ", " ", "More writing!"]
```

As you can see I now need to manually fold the whitespace.

Is there a way to match the whitespace as a single group along with the preceding sentence?

More generally:

Is there a way to achieve this in a way that supports Safari?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps match them `\w+(?: \w+)*[.?!]\s*` https://regex101.com/r/TjAhWq/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it'd be easier to just match non-sentence-terminators, then a sentence terminator, then 0 or more spaces:

```js
const str = 'More writing. More writing?    More writing!';
console.log(
  str.match(/[^.!?]+[.!?] */g)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting, you can match at least a single word followed by one of `.` `!` or `?` and match the trailing whitespace chars.

```
\w+(?:\s+\w+)*[.?!]\s*
```

- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:\s+\w+)*` Optionally repeat 1+ whitespace chars and 1+ word chars
- `[.?!]\s*` Match one of `.` `?` or `!` and optional trailing whitespace chars.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YzAdJ9/1)

```js
const s = "More writing. More writing?    More writing!";
console.log(s.match(/\w+(?:\s+\w+)*[.?!]\s*/g));
```

Comment: Good call! Thanks! Yes, was trying to make a non-capture group work, but couldn't.